# crystal report integration issue on setup and deployment

Tags: c#, wpf, crystal-reports, setup-deployment

I have a application with lot of reports using crystal reports.Now I want to setup and deploy my Project using visual studio setup wizard.But my problem is I want to install the application on another computer which has not installed the crystal report.The application run perfectly until it reaches the report part,it throw an error 'The type initializer for 'CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument' throw an exception'.

How do I reference crystal report dependencies on my setup project any body have idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To this You **need to instal crystal report run time engine** in that machine. In VS2010  they separated crystal reports from visual studio. So this problem is coming.

Comment: where do i get the crystal report run time engine ?

Comment: Just google sap crystal report runtime engine for Your Os and your  vs version  . follow this link                          http://1800thenerd.wordpress.com/2010/11/24/sap-crystal-reports-for-visual-studio-2010-files-needed-to-download/

Answer (score 2):

1. Right Click on Project(Setup and Deployment) which you created.
2. Select Properties then click on Prerequisites button
3. Checked option ' Crystal Report for the visual studio'
4. then click on ok button

Answer (score 1):

you can add add this references to your project:

```
1-CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.dll
2-CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.Report.dll
3-CrystalDecisions.ReportSource.dll
4-CrystalDecisions.Shared.dll
5-CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms.dll
6-CrystalKeyCodeLib.dll
```

Comment: I added this already on my application under references tab.But its not showing under the Detected Dependecies